# Java API for SQL Data Definition Language

Tags: java, sql, database, ddl

Before I write one, is there a Java API for manipulating a database. Like an object orientated wrapper around `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData`, with support for things like `Schema.createTable(name, columns)`?

Obviously correct SQL statements should be executed in the background based on the DB in use.

I'm specifically interested in an API for performing DDL statements.

Comment: Have you looked into one of the many ORM frameworks available?

Comment: Yes, and they provide nice APIs for DML. I'm interested in DDL APIs.

Comment: Ah, got it. You may want to alter your question title to make it more clear that you're looking for a DDL API and not a DML API (maybe "Java API for defining a database")

Comment: Yes, you're right. Re-reading the question the whole DDL requirement isn't obvious.

Comment: JOOQ greatly supports DML api, but it's only free for open source databases... if you have enough money to use on a commercial db maybe you could consider using it...
unfortunately QueryDSL has dropped DDL manipulation support.
Apache DdlUtils is left alone, new dbs are not supported ..
play sql dialects is newer than DdlUtils but doesn't cover many dbs and need contribution...
Liquibase is a promising abstract Migration Util (best database support, i've seen), but it can only used solely as a migration tool mostly in XML format, its' java api is not fluent for java programmers to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DdlUtils from Apache does this https://db.apache.org/ddlutils/

Answer (score 2):

Many object-relational mapping frameworks come with tools to generate domain model classes out of an existing schema, or create (or even update) a schema to match the domain model classes.

In particular, hibernate can do this, see

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#toolsetguide-s1

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, but I'll look at the source - it may contain what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember some tools such as NetBeans can create/ modify database schemas on-the-fly. You could have a look at the source code if you don't find a specific library.

Comment: So, no such API readily available as a stand alone package, but probably exists within existing open source software. Accepting as the closest thing to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered uisng straight JDBC calls ?

For control and security reasons I like to separate DDL and DML with ORM and JDBC respectively. This allows less experienced coders to focus on data manipulation ( via hibernate ).

Likely just my "old school " bias....

Hibernate can do some DDL functions however I have not used it extensively for this . I believe it cannot create tables dynamically ( i.e. on a running existing DB ) for example .

```
public static void createEmployees()
{
    Connection con = getConnection();

    String createString;
    createString = "create table Employees (" +
                        "Employee_ID INTEGER, " +
                        "Name VARCHAR(30))";
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(createString);
        stmt.close();
        con.close();

    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Employees Table Created");
}
```

Comment: I am currently using normal JDBC, but I want to dynamically retrieve forign key names, and create table in various different DB engines using the same code base. Requires some abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Java API for DDL in SQL: I've had to build one for my project, so I've published it as open-source: https://bitbucket.org/aragot/play-sql-dialects (APL2 license)

The license says it's ok to derive and include in a project for sale, as long as you respect the terms.

There's only a full dialect for PostgreSQL. Please feel free to contribute support for MySQL or Oracle. The unfortunate part is, Oracle and MySQL don't support transactional DDL, so in case of exception you need to recover the state of the database, which is the reason I didn't bother.

Example:

```
    if (rDialect.hasSchema("schema_test")) {
        rDialect.dropSchema("schema_test");
    }

    rDialect.createSchema("schema_test");
    rDialect.setDefaultSchema("schema_test");
    DDLColumn colID = new DDLColumn("ID", "#", null, null, null, DDLColumn.DataType.INTEGER, null, null, null);
    DDLColumn colPOSITION = new DDLColumn("POSITION", "POSITION", null, null, null, DDLColumn.DataType.TEXT, null, null, null);
    DDLColumn column1 = new DDLColumn("COL1", "Column 1", null, "integer-renderer", null, DDLColumn.DataType.INTEGER, null, null, null);
    DDLColumn column2 = new DDLColumn("COL2", "Column 2", null, "as-string", null, DDLColumn.DataType.TEXT, null, null, null);
    DDLTable table = new DDLTable(true, "test1", "Test 1", colID, colPOSITION, column1, column2);
    rDialect.createTable(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always thought that if you used prepared statements for your SQL then you could effortlessly change the database connector and switch to a different database, one that has the relevant JDBC connectors.

Comment: PreparedStatements are meant for DML operations.

Answer (score 0):

We are using the Pentaho Data Integration (ex-Kettle) with some success, although the Community Edition APIs are poorly documented.  It may require some hacking, but the abstraction and many features it provides may be worth it.